# Почему URLDownloadToFileA загружает старый файл?

Tags: c++, winapi, сеть

У меня в приложении реализовано автообновление через функцию URLDownloadToFileA

```
    std::string UpdateLink ="https://мой_сайт.ru/update.exe";
    if (URLDownloadToFileA(0, UpdateLink.c_str(), name, 0, 0) != S_OK)return 0;
```

Только проблема в том,что когда я на своем сайте меняю `update.exe`,то `URLDownloadToFileA` скачивает почему то старый файл,а не новый.

Я предполагаю что файл где то сохраняется в кеше,но не имею понятия как это исправить.

Comment: Берет файл из кэша?

Comment: Mikhailo,я тоже так думаю,но как это исправить?

Comment: если скачивать через curl то норм? что в качестве вёб сервера nginx/apach/.. ? какие у него настройки?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75452/5045688 - здесь пишут, нужно вызвать `DeleteUrlCacheEntry`

Answer (score -1):

Нужно вызвать `DeleteUrlCacheEntry`.

stackoverflow.com/a/75452/5045688

Comment: Это не тянет на ответ. Опишите, почему так происходит. Зачем вызывать эту функцию. И хорошо бы ссылку на документацию.